# VSCODE What is the proper format for entering allowed character(s) in the setting.json editor screen using "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters"

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-value

I am trying to enter a character into the VSCODE settings.json screen using the editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters statement. I cannot find a format that it will accept for entering either a single character or multiple characters. I get a message indicating that it is expecting an object, and it shows {} as the default, but I cannot find a reference for entering the key/value pair for the object. I am on VSCODE version 1.63.

How would I enter a single character, "-" in my case, or multiple characters?

Comment: So just cut and paste.  `true` was automatically populated when I did it.

Answer (score 1):

The key should be the allowed character, with a value of true (to stop highlighting) or false (to force highlighting):

```
"editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
        "-": true,
        "+": false
    }
```

You can also set this by going to the UI version of the settings and adding each character in Editor › Unicode Highlight: Allowed Characters

Comment: Thanks, Roberil. That solved it.